# TableView with NO shadow

Tags: ios7, uiview, uitableview, mfslidemenu

I have a SlideMenu that i use this library https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu .
My main view project a shadow over my Menu view.
I read the documentary but i do not found anything helpfull.
Also I try this but do not work.

`self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;`

[image: my storyboard]

How I can DELETE this white shadow?
Is any propertie of uiview?
THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look more deep in the documentation and I found This

```
- (void) configureSlideLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
// Change to 0
layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
layer.masksToBounds = NO;
layer.shadowPath =[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds].CGPath;
}
```